# Can you use a charging IC to monitor charge and discharge current (or just charge?)

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, integrated-circuit, current-measurement, discharge

For my project I would like to incorporate coulomb counting/current measuring so I can calculate the SoC and capacity of batteries. However, I am not sure if you can monitor the charge *and* discharge current with a charging IC because it is specifically for charging, but because it is connected to the terminals of the battery I am unsure if that is the case. Can you measure both the charge *and* discharge current with a charging IC?

Answer (score 4):

"Charging IC" is vague/broad. There are integrated circuits that incorporate battery charge controllers, MPPT controllers, coulomb counters, and serial communications all in one (e.g. [LTC4015](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4015.html#product-overview)). Then there are ICs which are just one of those things. Generally speaking, if a charge controller contains a coulomb counter, it monitors current to and from the battery and represents them as positive/negative values.

So in essence, "yes" is the answer to your question, but with a big caveat of "it depends" on the features of the IC you select.

Comment: Nordic released power management chip like the nPM1300 which integrates power supply, battery charger, fuel gauge and even more. Those chips would only apply in very specific cases but might be an all in solution that OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The charging IC does not know or care about state of charge (SoC). That's the job of the BMS, not the charger.

Yes, the BMS does measure current in either direction and it does evaluate the SoC both while charging (negative current) and discharging (positive current).

In a small battery, an all-in-one BMS IC (such as from TI) measures the current accurately by measuring the voltage across a shunt resistor. Then, it passes that reading to a second IC (a "fuel gauge") that integrates the current to evaluate the SoC.

You seem to want to do the evaluation in your own hardware. That's fine, but know that the "fuel gauge" ICs already do that, and do it well. Today, it makes little sense to reinvent the wheel for a small battery. Just use those ready-made ICs.